# IP-KVM (ADDER Ipeps in my case): Easy Firewall Traversal

Tags: firewall, hardware, remote-access

I am experimenting with a nice IP KVM, Adder IPEPS:
www.adder.com/uk/products/IPEPS.aspx

It has a built-in VNC server and one can connect to it using any VNC client.  My version also allows local access using physical keyboard-mouse-monitor.  However, the box does not seem to have built-in outward tunneling software that would allow me to connect to the unit remotely over the Internet, while the unit is behind a firewall.  Teamviewer and LogMeIn are some of the programs that allow the functionality that I am looking for, but only for Windows PCs, not for IP-KVMs.

I would like to create a solution that when we send a field engineer to a customer, they will hook-up the IPEPS to our product (an embedded Linux machine) and our engineers will be able to assist him remotely from our lab.  The client's IT staff should not have to do any work, they would just give their OK.

Does anybody have experience with BOMGAR (www.Bomgar.com)?

TIA,
Radim

UPDATE001:
After more research and thought, I am leaning toward solution using a Windows laptop and  Epiphan KVM2USB: www.epiphan.com/kvm2usb.  The laptop would run TeamViewer or similar sw. Does anybody have hands-on experience with Epiphan KVM2USB?  Using the Adder IP-KVM would also work, I just do not like the extra layer/IP-hop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your place I would simply use LogMeIn on the field engineers laptop and VNC to the iPEPs from there. If you're starting with the assumption that you can't make any changes to the customer firewall then your only way in is to have some host on the customer site make a connection to you. I'm not familiar with the stuff at www.bomgar.com, but wouldn't it be cheaper to supply your engineer with a netbook?

JR

Comment: Thank you JR.  Yes, I am gravitating to such solution, please see my edit UPDATE001 above.